# Replacing desktop OS with type 1 hypervisor and guest OS

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

I'm keen to use virtual machines as exclusively as possible in place of traditional operating systems on my desktop computers. Currently I can do this by running Linux as a host operating system, Virtualbox and then my day to day guest OS for working on within that.

I don't like having to run a full OS, with it's regular updates etc just to be able to run a virtual machine. What I'd like is for the physical computer to boot a minimal type 1 hypervisor and for that to boot directly into a guest OS of my choosing.

I'm not sure if there are any type 1 hypervisors that could do this and support graphics, USB etc although I've read Hyper-V may be able to do this..

If this isn't currently something people do, are there any up and coming projects that will allow this to happen?

Comment: Your question is extremely broad. It is indeed possible to boot directly to Type-1 hypervisor.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/473034/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-bare-metal-hypervisor-on-my-laptop?rq=1 yeah I think this is a duplicate of this one actually except more specific re hardware support