# Server Virtualization on Ubuntu Server or Something Else

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor, bare-metal

***Disclaimer***
I have little experience with Linux, VMware, or server stuff.
Also, I had posted this question originally at https://serverfault.com/questions/490037/server-virtualization-on-ubuntu-server-or-something-else
It was voted down and closed. I was told I should have posted here.

My goal is run Ubuntu Server VMs (or possibly another, smaller linux distribution) with exception of possibly 1 windows server instance.

---

<strike>**What I've done so far**
Copied the gz from a usb thumb to a folder I made called /vm_tgz
Changed directory to /vm_tgz/vmware-server-distrib/
Executed sudo -s -H
Executed ./vmware-install.pl</strike>

I get prompted for a C compiler. 
I exited the install and ran apt-get install gcc.
Executed ./vwmare-install.pl again

This time I make it past the prompt for the compiler.
I know get asked for the linux headers.
I break out of the installer...
After reading around on the interwebs, I try creating a symlink at /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/build/include/linux with the following commands:

ln -s /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/build/include/generated/autoconf.h /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/build/include/linux/utsrelease.h

ln -s /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/build/include/generated/autoconf.h /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/build/include/linux/utsrelease.h

I run ./vmware-install.pl
I get past the prompt for the headers, but it fails when when trying to build the vmmon module.
Also, I see a previous error stating *conflicting types for poll_initwait*.

I saw a post about [installing VMware Server 2 on Ubuntu 11](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10761345), but I don't really understand the instructions. I checked for an install.sh and a patch file, but didn't see one.

[I found another post detailing the steps again](http://robertomurray.co.uk/blog/2011/install-vmware-server-2-on-ubutu-11-04-with-2-6-38-kernel/), but I still don't understand.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

[Install.sh](https://github.com/raducotescu/vmware-server-linux-2.6.3x-kernel/blob/master/vmware-server-2.0.x-kernel-2.6.3x-install.sh)
[Patch](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10761345)

---

**EDIT: A change of direction**

---

After taking the initial feedback to heart, it seems I'm trying to fit a square peg through a round hole.

I am not aimed at desktop virtualization, but rather server virtualization (I may have an instance of Windows Server in the mix), so I still want to go as "bare-metal" as possible.
I read [Alternatives to Esx](http://slashdot.org/topic/bi/open-source-alternatives-to-esx-2/).

This [article](https://superuser.com/a/152196/207336) recommends VirtualBox for desktop use, and Xen in an HVM mode or KVM for server virtualization.

I also saw a post where someone used TinyCore with VirtualBox, and though I am willing to give it a go, I'm a bit leery of the "fringe" linux distros. I've had much success with Ubuntu working with little effort.

At this point, I am looking for a "straight-forward" solution. If I need to scrub my Ubuntu install for KVM, and KVM will "just work", perfect! If I need to pick a better stack, ok, but what?

Can someone steer me in this new direction? All opinions and suggestions will be taken to heart.

---

I see this post is bad enough to merit a -1...
Well, I just learned this type of product is called a Hypervisor. It's hard to know how to ask a question well without the proper vocabulary. 
I also understand the question may be a bit subjective. I really am trying to make this as objective as possible. This is why I included my disclaimer. I hope for some responses. I am going to continue to press to get a good solution for my home, and once I have it, I am going to post my results. Hopefully, the next person struggling to get started with Hypervisors will find this post and know how to approach solving this problem.

---

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you want to virtualize Windows Servers, I would go with HyperV from Microsoft. To give you some background, a hypervisor is basically and extremely lightweight OS that enables you to run VMs on top of it. That way, you don't have the weight of a full OS under your VMs when all you really need is a basic OS to run your multiple VMs on. HVs give you other perks too but this is just a primer, that info is documented better elsewhere.

If you aren't really going to run Windows OSes, then I would use a Linux based hypervisor, as HyperV will run Linux OSes, but to get *good* networking support you would need to run RHEL or CentOS, just FYI. I don't have experience with Linux based Hypervisors like the one you mentioned, but hopefully this will clear up some of your confusion.

Comment: I will mostly be running Ubuntu Server vms (or possibly another, smaller linux distro).